# Insert data from Android app to a database in XAMPP

Tags: android, xampp

I'm new in Android app developement. I want to develop a simple registration app that inserts the registration data (i.e. email, username, password) into a database in XAMPP (running in my Windows 10 system), with the Android app working under mobile network and my pc connected to wifi. 
I've already tried to do the same thing with the app and the pc connected to the same network and it works fine, but I have no idea how to do the same thing with the devices connected to different networks. 
How can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a valid IP for communicating over different networks, for example, you can use a **VPS** or **hosting**, or buy a **public IP Address** from your ISP, so your communications will not stay at localhost and all the data will be transferred with WWW.

note that you need to configure **NAT** settings on your router to set a public IPAddress to your PC

Comment: So the solution proposed in the other comment would not work with devices connected to different networks?

Comment: if you don't run the code in VPS or hosting, **NO**  they won't work on different networks

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an **API** for it. By API, I mean create a PHP page to do the registration. Then from the Android, you have to use a specific library called **Volley**, that lets you interact with the PHP file (send requests & get responses).

From the Android you can send your information (username, email, password) as a string query for the PHP file, then if you can get the response from the PHP file as a string or XML or JSON.